# Chai expect.to.throw errors are not equal

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

I'm trying to assert (using `expect`) that specific errors are thrown.

The errors are successfully caught, but the comparison of the errors fail. This includes `thrownCustomError` and `new CustomError()` as well as `thrownCustomError` and `customErrorInstance`. However it seems that using `expect().to.throw(CustomError, 'Custom error')` does work.

In my case I am specifically looking to assert custom errors that take parameters to produce the error message, so using the latter comparison is rather cumbersome.

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions much appreciated.

```
let chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const assert = chai.assert;

class CustomError extends Error{
    constructor() {
        super('Custom error')
    }
}

const throwFn = () => {
    throw new CustomError()
}

const customErrorInstance = new CustomError()

describe('CustomError Test', () => {
    it('should throw a CustomError (new)', () => {
        expect(throwFn).to.throw(new CustomError())
    })

    it('should throw a CustomError (const)', () => {
        expect(throwFn).to.throw(customErrorInstance)
    })

    it('should produce a strictly equal error', (done) => {
        try {
            throwFn()
        } catch (e) {
            assert(e === new CustomError(), 'Thrown error does not match new instance of error')
            assert(e === customErrorInstance, 'Throw error does not match const instance of error')
            done()
        }
        expect.fail()
    })
})
```

Output:

```
  CustomError Test
    1) should throw a CustomError (new)
    2) should throw a CustomError (const)
    3) should produce a strictly equal error


  0 passing (38ms)
  3 failing

  1) CustomError Test
       should throw a CustomError (new):

      AssertionError: expected [Function: throwFn] to throw 'Error: Custom error' but 'Error: Custom error' was thrown
      + expected - actual


      at Context.it (test.js:19:27)

  2) CustomError Test
       should throw a CustomError (const):

      AssertionError: expected [Function: throwFn] to throw 'Error: Custom error' but 'Error: Custom error' was thrown
      + expected - actual


      at Context.it (test.js:23:27)

  3) CustomError Test
       should produce a strictly equal error:
     AssertionError: Thrown error does not match new instance of error
      at Context.it (test.js:29:4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are testing instance in every time, so you need to make the `throwFn` throw that instance:

```
const customErrorInstance = new CustomError()

const throwFn = () => {
    throw customErrorInstance
}

// should throw a CustomError (const)
expect(throwFn).to.throw(customErrorInstance);
```

first test, you have to change to the class, because you are throwing a seperate instance in the function, and then trying to compare with a new instance in the expect, this will NEVER be true, by definition an instance is not strictly equal to a different instance EVER:

```
const throwFn = () => {
    throw new CustomError()
}

expect(throwFn).to.throw(CustomError)
```

Because what you were doing was trying to compare instance by doing `expect(throwFn).to.throw(new CustomError())`, this would never succeed.

### Here is your code touched up

```
let chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const assert = chai.assert;

class CustomError extends Error{
    constructor() {
        super('Custom error')
    }
}

const customErrorInstance = new CustomError()

const throwFn = () => {
    throw customErrorInstance;
}

describe('CustomError Test', () => {
    it('should throw a CustomError (new)', () => {
        expect(throwFn).to.throw(CustomError)
    })

    it('should throw a CustomError (const)', () => {
        expect(throwFn).to.throw(customErrorInstance)
    })

    it('should produce a strictly equal error', (done) => {
        try {
            throwFn()
        } catch (e) {
            assert(e !== new CustomError(), 'Thrown error instance is same as newly constructed! This is impossible!)
            assert(e === customErrorInstance, 'Throw error does not match const instance of error')
            done()
        }
        expect.fail()
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this isn't really a practical solution. Outside of naive examples, how can one expect to be able to specify the instance of the error thrown? As detailed above I am looking to verify the parameters the are passed to the error constructor. Consider a `expected: x got: y` error format. I need to verify the values of x and y

Comment: @DAnsermino yes we should never test instance of error, we should check type like how I fixed up your first example - `expect(throwFn).to.throw(CustomError)`. If you want to asserton the message then pass in a message `expect(throwFn).to.throw(CustomError, /should contain this/)`

Answer (score 2):

After digging deeper is appears that chai's evaluation of error equality is... strange. An error consists of a message and a stack trace. Since the stack trace is different depending on where the error is instantiated, equality cannot be achieved within `expect.to.throw` without throwing the same instance.

The only solution I can find that will assert only the error message is like this:

```
const a = new CustomError()
...
it('should produce a strictly equal error', (done) => {
    try {
        throwFn()
    } catch (e) {
        assert(e.message === a.message, 'Thrown error does not match new instance of error')
        done()
    }
    expect.fail()
})
```

(Note: at the time of writing there is an open PR to remove/modify this behavior https://github.com/chaijs/chai/pull/1220)